# Tower of Hanoi with forbidden move from source to destination (C)

Tags: c, function, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I am trying to write a recursive C function which would solve the tower of Hanoi , but with an extra restriction , that moving a disc from A (the source tower) to C (the destination tower) is forbidden , and vice versa.
For instance , moving a single disc from A to C or C to A , would require using the auxiliary tower (B).

I found a normal recursive Hanoi tower code from geeksforgeeks and checked [a CS page](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12130/hanoi-tower-with-forbidden-direct-move-from-source-to-destination)
which discussed the same problem , but I cant understand the mathematical algorithm (compared to a C function)

```
void tower(int n, char from, char to, char aux)
{
    if (n == 1 && (from=='B' || to=='B'))
    {
        printf("\n Move 1 from %c to %c", from, to);
        return;
    }
    if(n==1) {
       printf("\n Move 1 from %c to %c", from, aux);
       printf("\n Move 1 from %c to %c", aux, to);
       return;
    }

    tower(n-1, from, aux, to);

    if( from == 'B' || to=='B' ){
        printf("\n Move %d from %c to %c", n, from, to);
    }
    else{
        printf("\n Move %d from %c to %c", n, from, aux);
    }

    tower(n-1, aux, to, from);
}
```

this is the function from geeksforgeeks , modified to not violate the extra restriction , but now it keeps moving larger disks on top of the smaller disks.

I am wondering how this can be fixed and whether it is possible to modify this function for that restriction or not?
Thanks in advance !

edit: I am only allowed to move a single disc at a time , so some currently available algorithms cannot be implemented either.

Comment: You should be able to move as you please, just check if the top piece is smaller than the one you are moving, before allowing the move.

Comment: Hi, the restriction is part of the question (Im supposed to write it in a way that it would not move from source to destination)

Comment: [just translate this to C.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1973807/42667)

Comment: Hi, I am not allowed to move more than a single disc at a time :(

Comment: The standard Tower of Hanoi algorithm only allows you to move a single disc at a time.  I don’t understand what the additional restriction is meant to do.

Comment: the suggested algorithm moves n-1 disks in some moves in order to complete the tower , the extra restriction is that moving a disk from A to C or from C to A is not allowed.

Comment: Just move it to the first tower that doesn't have a larger piece on top and then move it to the actual destination.

Comment: but how can I be sure that there is no smaller one underneath it? I have placed some ifs to make sure it doesn't violate the extra restriction , but now it moves larger disks onto smaller disks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks everyone!
I found a C++ code so I'll post it down here with some modifications in case anyone has the same question later on:

```
void hanoi(int n,string src, string itm, string des)
{
    if (n>=1){
        hanoi((n-1),src,itm,des);
        cout<<"Move Plate "<<n<<" from "<<src <<" to "<<itm<<"\n";
        hanoi((n-1),des,itm,src);
        cout<<"Move Plate "<<n<<"from "<<itm <<" to "<<des<<"\n";
        hanoi((n-1),src,itm,des);
    }
}
```