# Towers of Hanoi problem when direct moves between left and right pegs are disallowed

Tags: java, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

Not a duplicate of

[Tower of Hanoi with forbidden move from source to destination (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105164/tower-of-hanoi-with-forbidden-move-from-source-to-destination-c)

[tower of hanoi - How to not skip over a peg every recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727627/tower-of-hanoi-how-to-not-skip-over-a-peg-every-recursion)

This is exercise 1.2. from the book *Concrete Mathematics* by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik:

Find the shortest sequence of moves that transfers a tower of n disks from the left peg A to the right peg B, if direct moves between A and B are disallowed. (Each move must be to or from the middle peg.)

After I solved the above problem mathematically, I thought to implement it using recursion in Java.

Here is the recursive method I wrote to solve the original problem:

```
public static void hanoi(int n, boolean left)
{
    if (n == 0) return;
    hanoi(n-1, !left);
    if (left) System.out.println(n + " left");
    else      System.out.println(n + " right");
    hanoi(n-1, !left);
}
```

For the original problem my program is compatible with what actually happens in real-world when you try to solve the problem, but for the modified version to work  I had to tweak my program in contradiction to the real world version as below.

```
public static void hanoi(int n, boolean left)
{
    if (n == 0) return;
    hanoi(n-1, left);
    if (!left) System.out.println(n + " left");
    else      System.out.println(n + " right");
    hanoi(n-1, !left);
    if (!left) System.out.println(n + " left");
    else      System.out.println(n + " right");
    hanoi(n-1, left);
}
```

As you can see my program never uses the middle peg and I falsely interchanged the print instructions for left and right. And yet this is the one that gave me the correct answers. For example for hanoi(2) one should get the following result:

1 right - 1 right - 2 right - 1 left - 1 left - 2 right - 1 right - 1 right

Could anyone help me understand why this happens or give an example of a recursive code (pseudocode or in Java) that is real-world-compatible?